# Set a transparent color

Tags: c#, colors

I have a `Color`, and I have a method that should return a more "transparent" version of that color. I tried the following method:

```
public static Color SetTransparency(int A, Color color)
{
   return Color.FromArgb(A, color.R, color.G, color.B);
}
```

but for some reason, no matter what the `A` is, the returned `Color`'s transparency level just won't change.

Any idea?

Comment: How are you using the `Color`?  The bug is probably there.

Comment: This should work, but where are you using the color? Some controls just don't play nice with alpha values.

Comment: @strager, I am using the Color as returned by `SetTransparency`, but it's not working in my control, funny.

Comment: The code doesn't compile (as you are using Color instead of color inside it), so you can't get anything out of that method. You should show the code that you are actually using instead. It's very hard to find an error in the code that you are using by looking at some other code that you are not using...

Comment: @Guffa, this is actually the code that I use. The `Color.R` is actually `color.R`, which I have fixed.

Comment: @Ngu: Then the problem is outside the method, because it does produce a color with the specified alpha value. You have to show how you use the method. (Actually the method is totally superflous, as it does the same as the already existing `Color.FromArgb(int, Color)` method.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, it looks okay to me, except that you're using `Color.R` (etc) instead of `color.R` - are you sure you're actually using the returned `Color` rather than assuming it will change the existing color? How are you determining that the "transparency level" won't change?

Here's an example showing that the alpha value is genuinely correct in the returned color:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

class Test
{
    static Color SetTransparency(int A, Color color)
    {
        return Color.FromArgb(A, color.R, color.G, color.B);
    }
    
    static void Main()
    {
        Color halfTransparent = SetTransparency(127, Colors.Black);
        Console.WriteLine(halfTransparent.A); // Prints 127
    }
}
```

No surprises there. It would be really helpful if you'd provide a short but complete program which demonstrates the exact problem you're having. Are you sure that whatever you're doing with the color even *supports* transparency?

Note that this method effectively already exists as [`Color.FromArgb(int, Color)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hstcth9(v=VS.100).aspx).

Comment: Yes, I'm using the returned `Color`.

Comment: I think maybe the component I use has an issue. I'll ask the component provider and see

Answer (score 5):

Just use the correct overload of FromArgb

```
var color = Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Red);
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with your naming.
I made a standard Windows Forms project, with 2 buttons and added some code, when clicking the buttons their respective colors do actually fade away.

And I agree with Jon Skeet, you are implementing a duplicate method, also all parameter names should begin with a lower case letter, so 'a' instead of 'A'

code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
    button2.BackColor = Color.Green;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Color c = button1.BackColor;
    button1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(Math.Max(c.A - 10, (byte)0), c.R, c.G, c.B);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Color c = button2.BackColor;
    button2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(Math.Max(c.A - 10, (byte)0), c.R, c.G, c.B);
}

public static Color SetTransparency(int a, Color color)
{
    return Color.FromArgb(a, color.R, color.G, color.B);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write an extension method for the `Color` class that returns a new `Color` with modified alpha value like this:

```
public static class ColorExtensions
{
    public static Color WithOpacity(this Color color, double opacity)
    {
        return Color.FromArgb((int)(opacity * 255), color);
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
var orange = Color.Orange;
var orange1 = orange.WithOpacity(0.5);

Console.WriteLine($@"R={orange.R} G={orange.G} B={orange.B} A={orange.A}");
Console.WriteLine($@"R={orange1.R} G={orange1.G} B={orange1.B} A={orange1.A}");
```

### [Live Demo](https://try.dot.net/?fromGist=2f2062b9b96f0d7c0db544aeae97e32b)